Why gravitational time dilation equals SR time dilation for objects free-falling from infinity?
In general relativity, the gravitational time dilation at a certain distance from a massive object matches the time dilation predicted by special relativity for an object free-falling from infinity to that location. Since SR time dilation arises purely from the algebraic properties of Lorentz transformations, why do these two different mechanisms produce the same time dilation factor in this scenario?
I'm seeking an intuitive explanation that uncovers the fundamental reason behind this equivalence without delving into complex technical details.

a free falling object in GR is locally in an inertial frame as required for SR

Can you prove that? Or can you give some reference?


why do these two different mechanisms produce the same time dilation factor in this scenario?

Well, you are making an assumption here, and I recommend you let go of that assumption. Do not assume something about mechanism; leave that open.

Crucially: GR subsumes SR.
GR content and SR content do not live side-by-side; GR covers the scope of SR, and beyond.
A specific aspect of that: in terms of GR: local measurement cannot distinguish between velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation - as a matter of principle.

There is the thought demonstration of a wheel-shaped space station where the space station is rotating for the purpose of pulling G's.
Levels of the space station that are further away from the axis of rotation have a larger velocity than levels of the space station that are closer to the axis of rotation. Correspondingly, for different levels there will be a difference in the amount of proper time that elapses.
In terms of GR:
In accordance with the principle of equivalence: GR facilitates description of the time effect in terms of gravitational potential.
Throughout all levels there is a gradient in gravitational potential. From level to level a different amount of proper time elapses, in accordance with difference of gravitational potential.
As a matter of principle:
Locally no measurement is available that would allow you to distinguish between velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation.

Distinction between velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation is not inherent in the phenomena. (There is a bit of a parallel with the principle of SR here: the magnet and coil thought experiment: making a distinction between the magnet as the moving part, or the coil as the moving part, is not inherent in the phenomena.)
Unfortunately, in introductions of GR as successor of SR it is common practice to treat gravitational time dilation as something that occurs in addition to velocity time dilation. (In approximate calculation the two can be treated as separate, and additive.) The thing is: it's better to emphasize from the start: GR subsumes SR, in the most profound sense.

There is another context where making a distinction between velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation leads away from understanding: the amount of proper time that elapses for clocks onboard a satellite in orbital motion around its primary.
In the case of the Earth:
In low Earth orbit: for clocks onboard a satellite in low Earth orbit a smaller amount of proper time elapses than for clocks on the surface of the Earth.
The constellation of GPS satellites orbits at an altitude of about 20,000 kilometer. For clocks onboard those satellites a larger amount of proper time elapses than for clocks on the surface of the Earth.
There is in fact an orbital altitude such that the amount of proper time that elapses for clocks onboard satellites at that orbital altitude comes out the same as for clocks on the surface of the Earth.
That case is discussed by Kevin Brown, in his resource 'Reflections on Relativity': Proper time in circular orbits
For equal amount of proper time elapsing Kevin Brown arrives at an orbital altitude of about 3000 kilometer.

There is another example:
Worldwide: for all clocks located at sea level the same amount of proper time elapses.
Now, a clock located at the Equator is circumnavigating the Earth's axis at about 1500 kilometers per hour. So if were to count velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation as distinct then you would not necessarily expect that for a clock on the Equator the same amount of proper time elapses as for a clock located at the pole.
About the Earth's rotation:
The rotating Earth is in hydrostatic equilibrium. There is an equatorial bulge; the equatorial Earth radius is about 21 kilometer larger than the polar radius.
About the state of equilibrium:
In terms of classical mechanics: it is a balance of two energies.
The extra height of the equatorial region is a reservoir of gravitational potential energy; if there would be opportunity for the Earth to contract to a perfect sphere then there would be release of gravitational potential energy. The Earth started out as a protoplanetary disk, and as that disk contracted towards spherical shape release of gravitational potential energy provided the energy to increase the rotation rate of the proto-Earth. (When a rotating system contracts the angular velocity increases, such that the angular momentum is conserved.) As long as over the course of contraction the rate of release of gravitational potential energy exceeds the rate of increase of kinetic energy the contraction continues. The contraction process has halted at the point where those two rates of change arrived at equilibrium.
Once arrived at the equilibrium shape there is no more opportunity to dissipate energy. There is a lot of energy in the system, but no opportunity to dissipate any of that energy. We can think of the equilibrium shape as a state of lowest possible total energy.
In the case of the Earth's gravity and the Earth's rotation: the gravitational effect is at a level of weakness such that the spatial effect of spacetime curvature is negligable as compared to the time effect of spacetime curvature.
Then in terms of GR the equilibrium shape of the Earth (equatorial bulge) can be thought of as a time equilibrium. A rotating celestial body will gravitationally contract to a shape such that everywhere over its surface (same geopotential height) the same amount of proper time elapses.

Cleonis wrote: "In approximate calculation the two can be treated as separate, and additive" - They are always multiplicative, for example if the kinematic time dilation relative to a local observer is 2 and the gravitational time dilation of the local observer to the external observer is 3 the time dilation of the moving object in the frame of the external observer is 23=6. In the weak field 0.0001+0.0001 is approximately the same as (1+0.0001)(1+0.0001)-1 but the latter always works.

This post doesn’t answer the question. It also refers to the “gravitational potential energy” that does not exist in General Relativity.

@Yukterez So we have that in the weak field just by the numbers one cannot say for sure. Very interesting. I'm not sure. A diagram that is available on wikipedia: Time dilation versus orbital height In the description of the diagram it is emphasized that distinction between gravitational time dilation and kinematic time dilation is an artefact. Can I persuade you to turn this addition-versus-multiplication into a answer-your-own-question post?

People would think I'm collecting reputation if I'd ask and answer my own questions, but this is trivial anyway, since for the velocity relative to the local clocks and rulers in whatever coordinates one takes the total time dilation dt/dτ and divides it by √gᵗᵗ to get the local gammafactor 1/√(1-v²) of the corresponding velocity, or multiply dt/dτ with √gₜₜ to get the local gammafactor relative to clocks and rulers at fixed spatial coordinates.

@Yukterez The stackexchange network explicitly encourages asking and answering own questions in situations where that serves the overall goal of making useful knowledge available. 2011 blog post by co-founder Jeff Atwood: It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions Ever since that policy has been carried forward: Can I answer my own question?

I am not a physicist, I am an amateur, so be very suspicious of this proposal of mine.
I will answer the question in an "intuitive" and simple way with 3 arguments:
1st Argument:
The "fundamental reason" requested by the OP and which imposes this identity between SR and GR in the specific case of comparison in free fall (in my opinion) is Einstein's Equivalence Principle, which served as the basis for the construction of the GR.
Consider a hypothetical graduated ruler that joins infinity to the center of the gravitational field of this suggested massive body.
Now, a small object abandoned at infinity is attracted by the gravitational field of the massive body in question, entering into free fall. Also consider that the free fall trajectory of this small object is close to, and parallel to, the ruler suggested above. For an observer located in the object in free fall, Einstein's Equivalence Principle applies.  Therefore, this observer situated on the small object in free fall can imagine himself at rest, and also that the ruler is moving at an accelerated rate ("upwards"), pulled by a hypothetical "motor", which accelerates it mechanically, as if this motor imitated and perfectly replaced the gravitational field and its gradient. In this hypothetical condition of total absence of the action of a gravitational field that aims to comply with the Principle of Equivalence, suppose that the motor accelerates the ruler to a certain speed, at which point this motor turns off, and the ruler assumes a constant speed. At this moment, and from this point on, the observer agrees that the acceleration of the ruler has ceased, and its speed becomes constant in accordance with the requirements of the SR, and the Lorentz transformations, allowing us to see that the value of this constant speed assumed by the ruler as soon as the motor turns off, is identical to the value of the escape velocity of the gravitational field (when its presence is considered) at that same point where the motor was hypothetically turned off.  The engine shutdown feature allows the observer to have enough time to measure the value of the ruler's velocity, which has become constant.
It is important to note that the free fall velocity of this object, which started from infinity, at each point of its "descent" trajectory, is always equal and opposite to the escape velocity of the gravitational field in question.
The engine shutdown feature was used because at this moment and at this point (whatever they may be), the value of the constant velocity measured is always identical to the escape velocity of the gravitational field of the massive body in question.
If the Equivalence Principle allows the gravitational field to be replaced by a supposed mechanism, because this device imitates it perfectly, then this means that the application of SR and the Lorentz factor used in this practice (only in vertical free fall) present a value identical to that found in the presence of the respective gravitational field, and this detail, in my opinion, answers the question posed by the OP.
2nd Argument
In the same way and for the same reasons as the 1st Argument, an observer in his laboratory, located in deep space, far from everything, analyzing an object close to him that is at rest, or at a constant speed, agrees that SR and the Lorentz transformations are valid there, regardless of the presence or action of a distant gravitational field in that location.
3rd Argument:
Also in agreement with the 2 previous arguments, it is important to realize that SR was born in 1905, eleven years before GR. Since there is no place in our universe free of a gravitational field, SR would be flawed for not having considered from its beginning the presence of gravity that fills the universe.
Note: These arguments refer specifically to cases of vertical free fall.

Only the first argument is valid. I noticed that the second and third arguments do not hold up.
